# How to achieve different headers on Squarespace

Tags: header, squarespace, custom-headers

I've tried everything remotely pertaining to Squarespace headers on other platforms and nothing is working. I have a Squarespace 7.1 website: marielapooley.com

I am needing to apply different header settings on different pages. I would love for my homepage to show the whole image behind the header and the other pages to show the tan color with white text for the header.

I have tried making the header "dynamic" or transparent for the homepage and that works great to show the whole image but then I cannot figure out how to customize the color to the header on the other pages to not be dynamic or transparent.

I have also tried custom CSS:

```
.page-section:nth-child(1) {padding-top:0!important}
```

and also:

```
#colleciton-123456 .page-section:nth-child(1) {padding-top:0!important}
```

Those custom CSS codes did nothing to the image or header.

The hex code for the color I want for the other pages (not Homepage) is: `#928A80`.

The collection # for the Homepage is: `#collection-65c3c4c71ae4e74d597f0ef3`.

The section data for the image on the Homepage is: `section[data-section-id="65c3ffc137ea2f44e9996f70"]`.

What can I try next?

Comment: (Minor item: you have a misspelling in `#colleciton-` which may be the cause of your problem).

Comment: Are you familiar with using your style explorer tools in your browser? If you have defined some styles and they are not applying, you can use the element picker and the page inspector to examine how the styles cascade onto an element. I use Firefox, but I think all browsers have these features these days.

Answer (score 0):

AHHHH! I just figured it out!!

I'm putting the answer here for anyone else having this issue and for my own reference.

`body:not(.homepage) header#header {
background-color: #928a80 !important;
}

Key points:

1. Must go under Website> Website Tools> Custom CSS
2. Make sure your Homepage is set up the way you want it to look and then add the code to change the other pages header color.
3. Customize your color by adding your Hex# in the background-color line